# How to change the decimal separator with awk/sed?

Tags: sed, awk

How to change number format (different decimal separator) from `XXXXXX.XXX` to `XXXXXX,XXX` using `sed` or `awk`?

Answer (score 13):

How rigorous do you want to be? You could change all `.` characters, as others have suggested, but that will allow a lot of false positives if you have more than just numbers. A bit stricter would be to require that there are digits on both sides of the point:

```
$ echo 123.324 2314.234 adfdasf.324 1234123.daf 255.255.255.0 adsf.asdf a1.1a |
>   sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\)\.\([[:digit:]]\)/\1,\2/g'
123,324 2314,234 adfdasf.324 1234123.daf 255,255,255,0 adsf.asdf a1,1a
```

That does allow changes in a couple of odd cases, namely `255.255.255.0` and `a1.1a`, but handles "normal" numbers cleanly.

Answer (score 8):

Wouldn't this be more accurate as the OP whas talking about numbers.. to make sure it is a leading number before the dot. The document could hold other dots that the OP don't want to substitute.

```
sed '/[0-9]\./s/\./,/g'
```

Answer (score 8):

## If you want to replace the decimal separator for cosmetic purposes

In most cases `tr` is probably the easiest way to substitute characters :

```
$ echo "0.3"|tr '.' ','
0,3
```

Of course if you deal with input mixing numbers and strings, you will need a more robust approach, like the one proposed by Michael J. Barber or even more.

## If you want to replace the decimal separator for computation purposes

By default `gawk` (GNU `awk`, i.e. the `awk` of most GNU/Linux distributions) uses the dot as decimal separator :

```
$ echo $LC_NUMERIC
fr_FR.UTF-8
$ echo "0.1 0.2"|awk '{print $1+$2}'
0.3
$ echo "0,1 0,2"|awk '{print $1+$2}'
0
```

However **you can force it to use the decimal separator of the current locale** using the `--use-lc-numeric` option :

```
$ echo $LC_NUMERIC
fr_FR.UTF-8
$ echo "0.1 0.2"|awk --use-lc-numeric '{print $1+$2}'
0
$ echo "0,1 0,2"|awk --use-lc-numeric '{print $1+$2}'
0,3
```

If the input format is different from the current locale, you can of course redefine LC_NUMERIC temporarily :

```
$ echo $LC_NUMERIC
fr_FR.UTF-8
$ echo "0.1 0.2"|LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8 awk --use-lc-numeric '{print $1+$2}'
0
$ echo "0,1 0,2"|LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF-8 awk --use-lc-numeric '{print $1+$2}'
0,3
```

([Credits and other links](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121007/26952))

Answer (score 2):

To substitute only the decimal commas in this line:

```
Total,"14333,374","1243750945,5","100,00%","100,00%","100,00%",1 639 600,"100,00%"
```

I used back-references (and MacOSX, so I need the -E option):

```
echo 'Total,"14333,374","1243750945,5","100,00%","100,00%","100,00%",1 639 600,"100,00%"'  | sed -E 's/("[0-9]+),([0-9]+%?")/\1\.\2/g'
```

resulting in

```
Total,"14333.374","1243750945.5","100.00%","100.00%","100.00%",1 639 600,"100.00%"
```

The sed command says: "Find every string of the form 'double quotes digit_1,digit_2, followed by one or zero %, double quotes' and replace it by first_match.second_match."

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
echo "XXX.XX" | sed s/\./,/g
```

Comment: this wouldn't work if you have dot separator in text

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
s/\./,/g
```

should serve what u want... unless u want something more special...

Answer (score 1):

if you have bash/ksh etc

```
var=XXX.XXX
echo ${var/./,}
```

Comment: Nice, here is a more cumbersome one that works in all POSIX shells: 
`var=XXX.XXX; echo ${var%.*},${var##*.}`

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is also tagged `awk`:

```
awk 'gsub(/\./,",")||1'
```

Comment: don't have to use ||1, `awk 'gsub(/\./,",")`

Comment: @ghostdog74 `gsub` returns the number of replacements, your version skips lines that do not contain at least one dot. I don't know enough about the OP's input data to omit the `||1`.