# Comma separated decimal places in a CSV file

Tags: python, r, amazon-web-services, csv

In a CSV file, one of the columns has values with decimal places separted by commas. For example, the values `15.4` is written as `15,4`.

Since it's a CSV file, when I try to import (to Python or R, for example) the importer thinks that the `15` belongs to a column and the `4` to another column. Since, in fact, `15,4` belongs to a single column, I end up having one less header than I need for the separation of the `15` and the `4`.

To solve this problem, I tought I could create one more header, and later I would concatenate the `15` and the `4` into a single column.

The problem is that each of these CSV files has 6GB. I wasn't able to open it in notepad or excel (in order to add a header by hand).

What would be a solution for this problem of having comma separated decimal places in a 6GB CSV file?

NOTE:

- I cannot replace all the `,` with `.` in the file, since other columns have string values with `,` in it.
- the separator in the CSV file is `,`, not `;`.
- It's not possible to generate the files again, replacing `15,4` with `15.4`.

Comment: How would you explain it to a computer? It can (probably) be done, but not if 15,4 should simetimes be 15.4 and other times 15 and 4.

Comment: It would help to see a small part of the file. For example, are the fields quoted?

Comment: You might also consider using `sed` to replace commas. See [this link for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439001/how-to-change-the-decimal-separator-with-awk-sed).

Answer (score 2):

When you read a csv file using Pandas, you can tell it what the decimal place will look like.
decimal=','
Here is the documentation.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: probably not what TS is looking for, since `,` is also a separator

Comment: See when PANDAS read a file, it goes through each column. If it finds all numbers and a comma, it will pick it up as a numerical column. Geez! Probably and then downvoting is not a great idea :) Assuming you downvoted.

Comment: whoops.. too fast... my apologies

Comment: Try using `skip=1` in `read.csv` and `header=FALSE`. That will skip the header line and generate your extra column. After that add the column headings with `colnames()`.